# Dojo.js has unvalidated data

Tags: javascript, security, dojo, fortify, phishing

I'm working with an e-learning course that a vendor created (who we no longer deal with) and when I upload the files through my company's security software (HP Fortify Scan) I'm getting multiple errors. I've corrected all the errors expect one. The error is in the dojo.js file and it has to do with a `url` variable being unvalidated. I'm sure it's a simple fix, but can someone explain what makes this unvalidated? And how can I validate this `url` variable?

Here is a screen shot of the error message with the code (I put the line number in a comment):

[image: Fortify Scan Screen Shot]

Code:

```
function xhr(url, options, returnDeferred){
    var response = util.parseArgs(
        url,
        util.deepCreate(defaultOptions, options),
        has('native-formdata') && options && options.data && options.data instanceof FormData
    );
    // THIS IS LINE 11540
    url = response.url; 
    options = response.options;

    var remover,
        last = function(){
            remover && remover();
        };

    //Make the Deferred object for this xhr request.
    var dfd = util.deferred(
        response,
        cancel,
        isValid,
        isReady,
        handleResponse,
        last
    );
    var _xhr = response.xhr = xhr._create();

    if(!_xhr){
        // If XHR factory somehow returns nothings,
        // cancel the deferred.
        dfd.cancel(new RequestError('XHR was not created'));
        return returnDeferred ? dfd : dfd.promise;
    }

    response.getHeader = function(headerName){
        return this.xhr.getResponseHeader(headerName);
    };

    if(addListeners){
        remover = addListeners(_xhr, dfd, response);
    }

    var data = options.data,
        async = !options.sync,
        method = options.method;

    try{
        // IE6 won't let you call apply() on the native function.
        // THIS IS LINE 11580
        _xhr.open(method, url, async, options.user || undefined, options.password || undefined);

        if(options.withCredentials){
            _xhr.withCredentials = options.withCredentials;
        }

        var headers = options.headers,
            contentType;
        if(headers){
            for(var hdr in headers){
                if(hdr.toLowerCase() === 'content-type'){
                    contentType = headers[hdr];
                }else if(headers[hdr]){
                    //Only add header if it has a value. This allows for instance, skipping
                    //insertion of X-Requested-With by specifying empty value.
                    _xhr.setRequestHeader(hdr, headers[hdr]);
                }
            }
        }

        if(contentType && contentType !== false){
            _xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        }
        if(!headers || !('X-Requested-With' in headers)){
            _xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        }

        if(util.notify){
            util.notify.emit('send', response, dfd.promise.cancel);
        }
        _xhr.send(data);
    }catch(e){
        dfd.reject(e);
    }

    watch(dfd);
    _xhr = null;

    return returnDeferred ? dfd : dfd.promise;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is not necessarily an error, it is just that HP Fortify Scan is pointing out a piece of code in dojo/request/xhr.js which may need your attention, in case your server code is not prepared for such an attack... You may validate the url at a higher level code in your application (possibly in your store) where you call the xhr(), not sure if that would satisfy HP Fortify.